# sqlalchemy.orm.exc.DetachedInstanceError: Parent instance <Draft at 0x7f39bec37828> is not bound to a Session

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

```
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.DetachedInstanceError: Parent instance <Draft at 0x7f39bec37828> is not bound to a Session; 
    lazy load operation of attribute 'childProccess' cannot proceed (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/bhk3)
```

I have a model like Draft and It have a relation to:

```
childProccess = relationship(
    childProccess,
    primaryjoin=and_(
        childProccess.draft_id == id,
    ),
)
```

When I am trying to query this I am getting this error which I posted

**EDIT**

my database logic setup something like this

```
ENGINE = None


def get_engine():
    global ENGINE

    if ENGINE is None:
        config_name = os.getenv("EXEC_ENVIRONMENT") or "dev"
        configurations = config_by_name[config_name]
        ENGINE = create_engine(
            configurations.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI,
            poolclass=configurations.SQLALCHEMY_POOLCLASS,
        )

    return ENGINE


def get_session() -> sessionmaker():
    session_maker = sessionmaker(bind=get_engine(), expire_on_commit=False)
    session = scoped_session(session_maker)
    return session()
```

Comment: Can you please share the setup logic for your database connection.

Comment: @MattSeymour question updated sir

Comment: The `Draft` instance isn't in the session.  Where does it come from?  Has it just been created?

Comment: @snakecharmerb yes it is . 1st I am creating draft . then some data addition to  `childProccess` . and when I query to draft then I am getting this error

Comment: So do `session.add(my_draft_instance)`?

Comment: yes   did this `session.add(draft)`
  then       `session.commit()`  after that same with      `childProccess`   and then again when trying to query it's giving this error

Comment: Do you have a session.close() call anywhere in your code?

Comment: yes when I call exception @MattSeymour but code is not going there I guess .

Comment: From the docs a common cause of this exception is calling close on a session or a session being close. I would comment out any code which closes sessions or tidies up to make sure you are not accidentally closing the session. Give it a try and see if the error persists.

Comment: @MattSeymour alright got the idea, you are right but thing is I must need to close sesssion and again get full object from database , why I can't retrieve data again when creating  `session = get_seesion()`  and then query ?

Comment: I think we need a [mre].